# Unknown column '..' in 'field list' -on inserting objects into mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to upload columns of data into a mySQL database. Below is a snippet of the code that runs into problem.

```
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute=("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (ts TIMESTAMP, col2 char(10), col3 decimal (7,2), col4 decimal (5,2), col5 decimal (7,2), col6 decimal (5,2))")
sql ="INSERT INTO table1 (ts, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)" 
sql += "VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql,(var2, var3, var4, var5, var6))
```

When running the code, I get the following error: 
`cursor.execute(sql,(var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Note that `var2` to `var6` are `decimal` objects converted from `str` objects.

**Update**: After removing the `=` from the problematic line, I now seem to have another error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ts' in 'field list'.`

Any ideas what am I doing incorrectly?

**Update** : Solution to the unknown column issue is to delete existing table,and run the script again

Comment: what are you saving in these variables **var2 to var6**?

Comment: You have overwritten `execute` with `cursor.execute=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `=` sign from your `cursor.excecute=(...)` and use this

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (ts TIMESTAMP, col2 char(10), col3 decimal (7,2), col4 decimal (5,2), col5 decimal (7,2), col6 decimal (5,2))")
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I now seem to have another error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ts' in 'field list'`. However, I have already indicated that this would be the timestamp column.

Comment: see if your table has been created or not? If it has been created see this ts field if it exist or not?

Comment: Thanks, got it! I deleted the existing table, then I ran the script again, it now works well.